# CDS Option Pricing (Missing Index Factor)

Tags: options, cds, credit-derivatives

I've read the OpenGamma paper https://quant.opengamma.io/CDS-Options-OpenGamma.pdf on **CDS Options**, and noticed a small discrepancy. So I wanted to double-check my understanding.

In **Section 6.4** the option payoff is defined as

[image: OptionPayoff]

with the default-adjusted forward portfolio swap price given by

[image: PortfolioSwapPrice]

And the exercise price given by

[image: ExercisePrice]

The portfolio swap price $V$ includes the index factor $f(T_e)$ as of option expiry $T_e$, as one would expect. Now, what I am wondering, is the exercise price $G$ not missing the index factor $f(T_{Inception})$ as of trade inception $T_{Inception}$? That is, formula `(70)` should be:

[image: CorrectedExercisePrice]

For example, say, we buy a swaption on **Version 2** (index factor **0.99** at trade time), and by expiry 2 more names have defaulted (so we are on Version 4 with factor 0.97). Then the exercise price we pay (at expiry) should use the factor as of when we **"entered into" the forward CDS** (so **0.99** as of trade inception), and not the current index factor. Whereas the live portfolio swap obviously uses the latest factor 0.97.

Does this make sense?

Comment: You may also like this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0111v3  section 3. Unless I'm confused, an exercise is on the portfolio consisting of version 4 of the index (having factor .97) and the recoveries of the 2 names that defaulted since the swaption was written on version of the index (having factor .99)?

Comment: You are right, when you exercise, you **enter** into **version 4 of the index** + you **receive the 2 protection payments**. However, you **exercise price** you pay should be based on the **idx factor of the original version**, see e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFWBk.png